# mysql performance issues in SELECT

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have these tables:

```
IdToName: 

Id   Name 
1    A 
2    B 

RawData:

Son  Father 
B    A
```

I want to create a new table called Data, in which instead of string, I will have Id's, i.e.:

```
Data: 
Son    Father 
2      1
```

I do this using this query:

```
INSERT INTO `Data`
    SELECT L.`ID`, P.`ID`
    FROM   `IdToName` L,
           `IdToName` P,
           `RawData` T
    WHERE T.Father = P.Name
    AND   T.Son = L.Name
```

I have keys on RawData's son and father and on IdToName's Name. This query takes about 7 minutes for 2,800,000 lines. Does anyone have any idea how I can improve the performance for this?

Comment: do you have an index on your columns?

Comment: Please include the execution plan for the SELECT ... JOIN

Comment: What's the output of `EXAMPLE SELECT L.ID, P.ID <rest of the SELECT query>` ?

Comment: I don't know what an execution plan is:( I added keys using ALTER TABLE ADD KEY, aren't they the same as indexes for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The only apparent reason why that would be slow is the lack of propper indexes.

Please index Id in table IdToName to UNIQUE, and both columns in table RawData to INDEX.

Comment: you mean Data or RawData? as far as I know, adding indexes before an insertion slows things down.. As for RawData, I added keys - is this not the same?

Comment: Yes, I ment that table. You can also try **both.**

Answer (score 0):

Check the time of the query alone. I strongly suspect that what you have is really "MySQL performance issues in INSERT", and not "in SELECT". 7000 inserts per second is quite a lot, it might be the physical limit of your machine.

uhm, and btw [edit]: we don't know the exact  shape and content of your tables (and of memory), but I don't think in your case any index can help.